# Splashscreen API below Android 12

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am testing the splash screen API below Android 12 versions. It is working fine. But when I navigate to another activity a black screen appears before activity apperas.

Here is my values-31/themes file

```
<style name="Theme.CustomSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher_round</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">300</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
 </style>
```

this is my main themes.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.CustomSplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_background</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">300</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
    </style>
```

Now, I have to navigate to screen according to the authentication. So, I have made a splash screen activity. Here is the code for it.

```
class SplashActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
        if (sharedPreferenceUtils.preferenceGetBoolean(Utils.PreferenceKey.isLoggedIn, false)) {
            startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, HomeActivity::class.java))
        } else {
            startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, LoginActivity::class.java))
        }
        finish()
    }
}
```

I have attached the video for the issue I am facing.

[image]